# $P(X|Y) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i|Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

What is the interpretation of such statement:
 $$\mathbb P(X|Y) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb P(X_i|Y)$$ 
where $X=(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$?

Comment: What would the interpretation be if there were no $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

It means that $X_1, ... X_n$ are conditionally independent given $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer and comment, here is a Bayesian graph to represent your scenario:

[image]
Resources for further information:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network
- https://ermongroup.github.io/cs228-notes/representation/directed/